# Refresh my list with Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am using iscroll and handlebars.js creating an infinite scroll list.

My template:

```
    <div id='iscrollwrapper'>
    <div id="scroller">
        <ul class="media-list">
            {{#each items}}
            <li class="media well well-sm">
              <a class="pull-left" href="#"> 
                   <img class="media-object" src='{{escape thumbnailimglink}}' alt="...">
              </a>        
              <div class="media-body" onclick="window.location.href='{{escape clickthrulink}}';">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">{{description}}</h4>
                    {{discount}}
              </div>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my JS, I am using itemsData to render the list,

```
    var itemsData = {
    test: 'mytest',
    items:  [
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
       {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
    ]
};

var itemsData2 = {
        test: 'mytest',
        items:  [
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me2',discount:'50%'},
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me2',discount:'50%'},
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me2',discount:'50%'},
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me2',discount:'50%'},
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me2',discount:'50%'},
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
           {thumbnailimglink:'img/sample.jpg', clickthrulink:'http://www.google.com',description:'this is me',discount:'50%'},
        ]
    };
Handlebars.registerHelper('escape',function(variable){
    return variable.replace(/(['"])/g, '\\$1'); 
});
var homePage = commonModule.render('home', itemsData);
```

inside of my commonModule.render I am using handlebars.js,

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(this.tmpl_cache[tmpl_name]);
        console.log('tmpl_data:'+tmpl_data);
        var html = template(tmpl_data);
        console.log('htm:'+ html);
        return html;
```

Then the html is added to the container div and it is working good.

Now on the template, I want to have a button, when it is clicked, I will use itemData2 to render the list and refresh the existing container.  Any idea how to do it?

Thanks
Hammer

Comment: By the way, it's TOTALLY unrelated but recently I switched from handlebars to angularjs. if you have lots of modals, views and controllers, angular is much more easier to develop and maintain. in my case, it saved my life.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing a higher lvl function to render your data, for example,

```
renderWithHandlebars(target, template, context):
    compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile($(template).html())
    $(target).html(compiledTemplate(context))
```

Then, in the initial rendering, call `renderWithHandlebars(your_target, your_template, itemsData)`.
After a while, if you want to render the same template to the same DOM element using a different context, just call renderWithHandlebars again with different context.

In your case, your handlebars template is context agnostic, ie. it doesn't have to know whether the context is equal to itemsData or itemsData2. So, calling `renderWithHandlebars(your_target, your_template, itemsData2)` when a button is clicked should work.

Since you are using `target.html(...)` method, you can re-render again and again, only the last rendering will be visible.